# Report design not valid. Field not found Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Im trying to create a basic jasper report with `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`. In there im having a list of objects inside the javabean.

```
public class Course {

    private int id;
    private List<Student> students;
}
```

Student object looks like

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int id;
}
```

I want to print student information inside my report. This is how my jrxml looks like

```
 <subDataset name="dataset1" uuid="09015d96-ad5a-4fed-aa9e-19d25e02e205">
 <field name="students" class="java.util.List">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[students]]></fieldDescription>
 </field>
</subDataset>

<field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="students" class="java.util.List"/>
<field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>

<componentElement>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="400" height="20"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="dataset1">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{students})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="20" width="400">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                            <box leftPadding="10">
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>

                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
```

But when i run this im getting

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
     1. Field not found : name
Report design not valid : 
     1. Field not found : name
```

Im a beginner to jasper reports can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong here. Thanks

Comment: Can you suggest me the good tutorial for jasper reports

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/ this is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fount out the issue. name attribute should defined inside the `subdataset`. Otherwise it wont work

```
<subDataset name="dataset1" uuid="09015d96-ad5a-4fed-aa9e-19d25e02e205">
     <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
</subDataset>
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to define the fields before using it.

In your `jrxml`, you have three field defined `students` in the subDataSet, `id` and `students`. But you haven't defined `name` and using it in your `jrxml` and that's why you are getting this exception.

Try defining `name`, like

```
<field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have defined the name attribute in jrxml. still getting the same error :(

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Just for completeness: In iReport you also need to add fields - you will find them in Report inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a subreport. I launched your example in my local database without any problem.

This is my list of student objects:

```
private List<Student> getList(){
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    Connection con = ....; //Retrieve your connection the way you want
    ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("select name, id from students order by id");
    while (rs.next()){
        students.add(new Student(rs.getString(1), rs.getInt(2)));
    }
    con.close();
    return students;
}
```

This is how I passed my `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` object from my Java program:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("SUBREPORT_DATASOURCE", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(getList()));

String jasperPath = "....."; //where you have your compiled jasper report file
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperPath, params, new JREmptyDataSource(1));
```

This is the xlm main report "reportStudent.jrxml":

```
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="reportStudent" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DATASOURCE" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="125"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DATASOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["./reportStudent_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

And this is the one for the subreport "reportStudent_subreport1.jrxml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="reportStudent_subreport1" language="groovy" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.771561000000001"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="66" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="212" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="66" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="212" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

This is for just one list of students. You can iterate inside the main report and print your course id and students subreport in the detail band with just a little changes. Hope it helps to start with.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using a subreport ?

Comment: You could insert a table or crosstab in the detail section and print your student list. You will have to configure the necessary parameters to send them to that table/crosstab. Think that detail band is printed once an object in your JRBeanCollectionDataSource (a Course in your case)